# Unable to get row number - subquery in FROM must have an alias

Tags: postgresql

Hi I'm trying to get a row number but I keep getting the error `subquery in FROM must have an alias` not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Here is my code:

```
await pool.query('SELECT row_number() Over(lvls), * FROM (SELECT guild_id FROM levels WHERE guild_id = $1)', [message.guild.id]) `
```

Comment: The subquery (derived table) is unnecessary to begin with.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name why so? could you provide an example of how to query the row number?

Comment: Your query can be simplified to `SELECT row_number() Over(lvls), guild_id FROM levels WHERE guild_id = $1` - but in reality both will result in an error as `over(lvls)` is invalid to begin with.